# Using GDrive to download entire folder

Tags: 16.04, google-drive

is there a way to use GDrive to download an entire folder from Google Drive? I am unable to find a way, and I need to download the folder from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

Detailed steps to install and use gdrive can be found in this [web page](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/google-drive-cli-client-for-linux)  or [this one](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-access-google-drive-from-linux-gdrive/). 
Specifically, to download a folder the first step is to get it's ID using this command :

```
gdrive list --query "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

Then, just download your folder with this command :

```
gdrive download --recursive '<folderID>'
```

Comment: This method no longer works. Google won't let you sign in with it.

Comment: @MayurKulkarni: Sad news :(

Comment: I have tried and it works on my end @MayurKulkarni

Comment: It works. But currently it is not like an rsync, so for really big folders the download may timeout.